# How to properly iterate over arrays in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-structures

I am currently learning kotlin and therefore following the kotlin track on exercism. The following [exercise](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/5a915f3cf5604a7eb42fc4bb6e17b933) required me to calculate the Hamming difference between two Strings (so basically just counting the number of differences).

I got to the solution with the following code:

```
object Hamming {
    fun compute(dnaOne: String, dnaTwo: String): Int {
        if (dnaOne.length != dnaTwo.length) throw IllegalArgumentException("left and right strands must be of equal length.")
        var counter = 0
        for ((index, letter) in dnaOne.toCharArray().withIndex()) {
            if (letter != dnaTwo.toCharArray()[index]) {
                counter++
            }
        }
        return counter
    }
}
```

however, in the beginning I tried to do `dnaOne.split("").withIndex()` instead of `dnaOne.toCharArray().withIndex()` which did not work, it would literally stop after the first iteration and the following example 
`Hamming.compute("GGACGGATTCTG", "AGGACGGATTCT")` would return 1 instead of the correct integer 9 (which only gets returned when using `toCharArray`)

I would appreciate any explanation

Comment: Did you use `split("")` in both places you currently use `toCharArray()`?

Comment: Yes I did. 
With `split("")` it is the class `class java.util.ArrayList` while
`toCharArray()` converts the string to a class of `class [C`

I just dont see how that makes a difference in terms of iterating over it

Comment: Trying at https://pl.kotl.in/hM0BcjCdJ, I get the expected 9.

Comment: What did `dnaTwo.toCharArray()[index]` look like when you were using `dnaOne.split("").withIndex()`?

Comment: Side note: in both cases you are calling `split`/`toCharArray` on `dnaTwo` way too many times, do it just once before the loop.

Comment: thx!! I changed that :)
I dont know why it returned 1 before, it's working with `split("")` now as well..

I will generally read more into Arrays, Lists and ArrayLists since this still confuses me.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: May be you can evaluate a more compact and functional-oriented implementation, based on `zip` function:
`return dnaOne.zip(dnaTwo).filter { p -> p.first != p.second }.size` ...

Comment: just looked up `zip` and `filter`.

That seems much better, thank you so much! Instead of `p` we could even just do `return dnaOne.zip(dnaTwo).filter { it.first != it.second }.size` right?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simplify this by using the built-in [`CharSequence.zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/zip.html) function because String`implements`CharSequence` in Kotlin.

According to the documentation for `zip`:

> Returns a list of pairs built from the characters of `this` and the [other] char sequences with the same index
>
> The returned list has length of the shortest char sequence.

Which means we will get a `List<Pair<Char,Char>>` back (a list of pairs of letters in the same positions). Now that we have this, we can use [`Iterable.count`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/count.html) to determine how many of them are different.

I implemented this as an extension function on `String` rather than in an `object`:

```
fun String.hamming(other: String): Int =
    if(this.length != other.length) {
       throw IllegalArgumentException("String lengths must match")
    } else {
       this.zip(other).count { it.first != it.second }
    }
```

This also becomes a single expression now.

And to call this:

```
val ham = "GGACGGATTCTG".hamming("AGGACGGATTCT")
println("Hamming distance: $ham")
```